# Highcharts js different when installed with bower

Tags: highcharts, bower

Highcharts js seems to be different when installed through bower as opposed to just using the one from http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js, even though they both say v5.0.14. I've tried comparing them with beyond compare and the two files seem significantly different. But what's worse, the two behave differently as well. What's the explanation for this?

Comment: Can you point out the difference? Preferably with screenshots.

Comment: The one from bower seems to ignore `plotLines` options for example. The plot line always stays on default grey whatever I pass in. Works as expected when using the non-bower highchars.js directly.

Comment: I tested both versions (from CDN and from Bower) on this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/e9w4rm1u/ and it seems they both work identically. Could you tell me how do you install the Bower package? Also, provide me with your example. Follow this instruction of installing Highcharts from Bower: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/getting-started/install-from-bower.

Answer (score 0):

Turned out I was referencing the wrong file. As of v5 there is a [styled](https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-design-and-style/style-by-css) version now located in the /js folder. 
So make sure you reference bower_components/highcharts/highcharts.js and not bower_components/highcharts/js/highcharts.js because that's the styled version.